# Example of a direct-mapped cache

Tags: computer-architecture

[image]

Please can any one describe this picture? I am not getting that 4 entries to 001.

Comment: This is not twitter. Please use full sentences and traditional spellings.

Answer (score 1):

There are 8 blocks in cache which are represented as (000,001,...111 ) 
There are 32 blocks in Memory which are represented as (00000,00001,...11111)
So in Direct Mapped cache the 0 th block will have all the entries of main memory where 0,8,16,24 this is by 0 mod 8 = 8 mod 8= 16 mod 8 = 24 mod 8 =0

Here the entries will be for 1 th block of a cache (001) will have entries of main memory where 1,9,17,25 this is by 1 mod 8 = 9 mod 8= 17 mod 8 = 25 mod 8 =1